# Why does this code not work after I input name?

Tags: python

```
import random

name=input("What is your name?")
print ("Alright",name,"welcome to your maths quiz")
score=0

level_of_difficulty= input("What level of difficulty are you working at? Press 1 for low, 2 for intermediate or 3 for high")
if level_of_difficulty == 1:
    for question_num in range(1, 11):
            ops = ['+', '-', '*']
            number_1=random.randrange(1,10)
            number_2=random.randrange(1,10)
            operation = random.choice(ops)
            maths = eval(str(number_1) + operation + str(number_2))
            print('\nQuestion number: {}'.format(question_num))
            print ("The question is",number_1,operation,number_2)

            Answer=int(input ("What is your answer:"))
            if Answer==maths:
                print ("Correct")
                score=score+1
            else:
                print ("Incorrect. The actual answer is",maths)

            print("Well done you scored",score,"out of 10")
if level_of_difficulty == 2:
    for question_num in range(1, 11):
            ops = ['+', '-', '*']
            number_1=random.randrange(1,20)
            number_2=random.randrange(1,20)
            operation = random.choice(ops)
            maths = eval(str(number_1) + operation + str(number_2))
            print('\nQuestion number: {}'.format(question_num))
            print ("The question is",number_1,operation,number_2)

            Answer=int(input ("What is your answer:"))
            if Answer==maths:
                print ("Correct")
                score=score+1
            else:
                print ("Incorrect. The actual answer is",maths)

            print("Well done you scored",score,"out of 10")
if level_of_difficulty == 3:
    for question_num in range(1, 11):
            ops = ['+', '-', '*',"/"]
            number_1=random.randrange(1,20)
            number_2=random.randrange(1,20)
            operation = random.choice(ops)
            maths = eval(str(number_1) + operation + str(number_2))
            print('\nQuestion number: {}'.format(question_num))
            print ("The question is",number_1,operation,number_2)

            Answer=int(input ("What is your answer:"))
            if Answer==maths:
                print ("Correct")
                score=score+1
            else:
                print ("Incorrect. The actual answer is",maths)

    print("Well done you scored",score,"out of 10")
```

Why would this not work? There is no invalid syntax. So I don't know why it is not working.

Comment: what python version are you using?

Comment: `Why would this not work, there is no invalid syntax so I dont know why its not working` - You're going to need a lot more information than that to attract help here.  SO is not a personal debugging service for huge chunks of code.

Comment: I am using pyscripter but I think its 3.1

Comment: "_gh hgf hgfh fghf gfhfhfhfghgfhgf hfhghgf_" -- Huh? BTW, add some more information. We cannot read your mind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have

```
level_of_difficulty= input("What level of difficulty are you working at? Press 1 for low, 2 for intermediate or 3 for high")

if level_of_difficulty == 1:
    ...
if level_of_difficulty == 2:
    ...
if level_of_difficulty == 3:
    ...
```

But `input()` returns a string, not an `int`. Convert the input into an `int` by changing

```
level_of_difficulty= input("What level of difficulty are you working at? Press 1 for low, 2 for intermediate or 3 for high")
```

to

```
level_of_difficulty= int(input("What level of difficulty are you working at? Press 1 for low, 2 for intermediate or 3 for high"))
```

Answer (score 1):

The method `input()` tries to execute the user's input as code.  It is equivalent to `eval(raw_input(prompt))`.  Here you should use `name = raw_input("What is your name?")`.

While your question is very unclear and I don't actually know what your problem is, I cleaned up your code and this works in Python 2:

```
import random

name = raw_input("What is your name?\n")
print("Alright {0} welcome to your maths quiz".format(name))
score = 0

level_of_difficulty = input(("What level of difficulty are you working at?\n"
                             "Press 1 for low, 2 for intermediate "
                             "or 3 for high\n"))

if level_of_difficulty == 3:
    ops = ['+', '-', '*', '/']
else:
    ops = ['+', '-', '*']

for question_num in range(1, 11):
    if level_of_difficulty == 1:
        number_1 = random.randrange(1, 10)
        number_2 = random.randrange(1, 10)
    else:
        number_1 = random.randrange(1, 20)
        number_2 = random.randrange(1, 20)

    operation = random.choice(ops)
    maths = eval(str(number_1) + operation + str(number_2))
    print('\n*** Question {0} ***'.format(question_num))
    print("The question is {0} {1} {2}".format(number_1,
                                               operation,
                                               number_2))

    answer = int(raw_input("What is your answer: "))
    if answer == maths:
        print("Correct")
        score = score + 1
    else:
        print("Incorrect. The actual answer is {0}".format(maths))

print("Well done you scored {0} out of 10".format(score))
```

Comment: I believe that the OP is using python3

Comment: While OP did say that it seems to get past the name in python3 *shrug*

Comment: In reply to mjalkio thanks a lot but your program uses the same numbers for each question which isn't the desired outcome

Answer (score 1):

Your code doenst run after asking for a difficulty level. The point is that input is a string or whatever. so you ask python to compare apples and oranges if apple == orange: do this. that doesnt work.

to solve this you need to transform your input into an orange in this case a integer a number. to do this ad int() 'around' your input. like this

```
level_of_difficulty= int(input("What level of difficulty are you working at? Press 1 for low, 2 for intermediate or 3 for high"))
```

goodluck